# How to pass a writable argument to an attribute directive using the attribute itself in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When writing an attribute directive, I would like to pass an argument to the directive which is a property path that can be written to.  (Much like how the ng-model attribute works on inputs.)  How do I set up the directive so that I can write to it?

Example: Take the Draggable directive found on the [AngularJS website](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).  You use it by simply declaring the attribute on the element.

```
<span draggable>Drag ME</span>
```

I want to create a new directive which looks like this:

```
<span draggable="somePath.someObj">Drag ME</span>
```

and as things are watched inside the directive (say the position of the element), values will be written to the object located at somePath.someObj on the scope.

Here is the base directive I am starting with:

```
angular.module('drag', []).
  directive('draggable', function($document) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
      var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
      element.css({
       position: 'relative',
       border: '1px solid red',
       backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
       cursor: 'pointer'
      });
      element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
        // Prevent default dragging of selected content
        event.preventDefault();
        startX = event.screenX - x;
        startY = event.screenY - y;
        $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
      });

      function mousemove(event) {
        y = event.screenY - startY;
        x = event.screenX - startX;
        element.css({
          top: y + 'px',
          left:  x + 'px'
        });
      }

      function mouseup() {
        $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
      }
    }
  });
```

(The Plunkr is found on the website.  Not sure what the actual link is)

Comment: To link to things just paste the link or `[url goes here](text to display)`

Comment: Can you provide the code for your directive so far?  But most likely you will need to use a link function in your directive

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Thanks, but my problem is finding the actual link of the Plunkr that I want to link to, not how to link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gDslB) demonstrating how to do this using the [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) service inside of a [scope.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) function call.

Relevant HTML:

```
<section class="text-center" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a href="#" my-directive="user.name">Hover me</a><br>
  Current value of 'user.name': {{user.name}}
</section>
```

Relevant Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'value from controller'
  };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function($parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('mouseenter', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          $parse(attrs.myDirective).assign(scope, 'value from directive');
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$parse` service, see docs with example here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse)